# Can't parse JSON data to listview(_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>')

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Cant parse JSON data from a URL, getting error "_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr>')".
So You can check the datas from the link. and let me know what I am doing wrong, Thanks in advance.

I tried using map, not worked.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ui_hotel_list(),
    );
  }
}



class ui_hotel_list extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ui_hotel_listState createState() => _ui_hotel_listState();
}

class _ui_hotel_listState extends State<ui_hotel_list> {
  List hotels;
  Future<List> _getHotels() async {
    String serviceURL="**************************************************************************************";
    var response = await http.get(serviceURL);


    return json.decode(response.body.toString());
  }
  printv() async {
    hotels= await _getHotels();
    for(var i=0;i<hotels.length;i++) {
      print(hotels[i]["hotels"]["name"]);
    }

  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this._getHotels();
    this.printv();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        itemCount: hotels.length==0?0:hotels.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(hotels[index]["hotels"]["name"]),
            subtitle:Text(hotels[index]["hotels"]["location"]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get the data from that URL and show in my listview. What i need to add, please suggest me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic and access like this 
You can paste and run full code below

code snippet

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseData["hotels"].length; i++) {
      print(responseData["hotels"][i]["name"]);
    }

...
ListTile(
                    title: Text(responseData["hotels"][index]["name"]),
                    subtitle: Text(responseData["hotels"][index]["location"]),
                  ),
```

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ui_hotel_list(),
    );
  }
}

class ui_hotel_list extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ui_hotel_listState createState() => _ui_hotel_listState();
}

class _ui_hotel_listState extends State<ui_hotel_list> {
  dynamic responseData;
  bool loading = false;

  Future<dynamic> _getHotels() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    String serviceURL =
        "https://baseURL/api/v2/search/filtered/?checkin=08-11-2019&checkout=09-11-2019&adults=2&rooms=1&location=1&page=1";
    var response = await http.get(serviceURL);

    return json.decode(response.body.toString());
  }

  printv() async {
    responseData = await _getHotels();
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < responseData["hotels"].length; i++) {
      print(responseData["hotels"][i]["name"]);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this._getHotels();
    this.printv();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Container(height: 100, width: 100, child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              itemCount: responseData["hotels"].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(responseData["hotels"][index]["name"]),
                    subtitle: Text(responseData["hotels"][index]["location"]),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: oh man! it worked like a charm!! I am new on JSON so i need your suggestion how to retrieve data from like:
"hotel_images": [
        [
            "https://xercesblue.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/hotel/94383989.jpg"
        ],
        [
            "https://xercesblue.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/hotel/89779171.jpg"
        ],
        [
            "https://xercesblue.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/hotel/89779173.jpg"
        ],

this kind of JSON format, how can I retrieve data? I tried responseData["hotel_images"][0]
doesnt work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help.

Comment: You can paste your json string to https://quicktype.io/ , it will give you correct class and how to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem comes from the `_getHotels()` method. It says it returns a `Future<List>`, because that is what you expect. But Flutter has no way to know what the URL you provided holds (`https://amarroom...`). It turns out that when you post an HTTP request with that URL, it returns:

```
{
"special_amenities": [
    1,
    5,
    11,
    48,
    45
],
"facets": {
    "neighborhood": [
        [
...
}
```

which is not a `List`, it is a JSON, that is, a `Map<String, dynamic>` in Dart. So your `_getHotels()` function should not return a `Future<List>`, it should return a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Then you can do whatever you want to your `Map<String, dynamic>` returning from that function and turn it into a `List`, if that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but stuck on this:
  hotels= await _getHotels();
  hotel= hotels.values.toList();
    print(hotel);
    for(var i=0;i<hotel.length;i++) {
      print(hotel[i]["hotels"]["name"]); //here is problem '_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')'
    }

Comment: It is a similar issue: you are expecting an int value where a String is actually being retrieved.